# Identification of unknown bagworm (Singapore)

Tags: entomology, species-identification

This bagworm was found in Singapore (near McRitchie Reservoir) some time in June 2012.

This is the plant from which the bagworms were obtained:
[image]

A few examples of the bagworms:
[image]
[image]

The bagworm when dissected out of its bag:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is the plant Banana (looks similar)? If so, the bagworm (Psychidae) *Kophene cuprea* could be a possibility, since it is considered a pest on banana ([Mosich & Larsen, 1978](https://books.google.se/books?id=I4siBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA606#v=onepage&q&f=false)). The larval case is also supposed to be conical, but I cannot find an online picture for comparison.