# What is this animal that hides in dustlike structure?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera

I'd like help identifying the species of animal in these two photos. There's some dust(or dust-like substance) with something alive inside of it (possibly a larva or I don't really know what to call it). This appeared in a couple of hours in the wall. Please, try to even just guess what this could be (I can't think of anything!). Very odd... 
I don't even know what tags I hsould use for this!

Thanks in advance
[image]
new photo
[image]

Comment: How big is it? Where do you live? It's very hard to see any animal in the photos, but for example Case Bearing Moth larvae use fibers to make the "case" that it lives in. Or maybe a carpet beetle larva that happened to hide in this dust.

Comment: it's a bedroom. there's a dust around in a room(I cleaned a lot), but when I just came there's was a very big humidity in the air(you know, the smell of it...). It's one of my relatives home and I'm very disturb about it.

Comment: I think it might be a moth larva. And I really don't think one larva is reason to be worried! Just remove it and keep an eye out for more of them, in dust or perhaps wool materials.

Comment: I've been here for three days now, and noticed this yesterday... I removed three of them(yesterday) and today more two. while I was gone(for about 2-3 hours outside to travel in the city) this one appear... that's why I'm worried :/

Comment: Sorry to hear that (even if it's still not an outright infestation). I'm no expert, but I would recommend more vacuming, removing of materials that they like, and if they keep coming, googling for clothes moth pest control.

Comment: Where in the world is this, what's the nearest City?

Comment: This might indeed be a moth larvae. If you already found six, there might be more. Moth larvae generally eat something organic like plants, cotton or wool. Search for this source, it might be a plant, carpet, curtain, cloths, etc.

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/28479/16866

Comment: There's a lot of animals that do that: https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:Reduvius_personatus,_Masked_Hunter_Bug_nymph_camouflaged_with_sand_grains.JPG

Answer (score 5):

This is likely a **case-bearing clothes moth (*Tinea pellionella*)**. 
Though more information and a better image would aid in confirming that to be the case.

Here are some pictures:

[image]

[image: http://www.discoverlife.org/IM/I_MWS/0711/320/Tinea_pellionella,I_MWS71144.jpg]

[image]