# Species identification: flaky worm

Tags: species-identification

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckukO.jpg)
[image]Recently our house got ABSOLUTELY INFESTED with the following creature.
Kindly identify.
Hapitat: damp shadowy regions of our house
Description: The outer flake is probably a shell, the shell is not very soft, not very hard. The smaller ones have really soft shells. I could not photograph it, but the shell houses a really small worm kind of thing that pokes out its head and then graples the wall or something and then pulls it shell to move. Movement speed is pretty small say about 5mm per second at max. The worm was black coloured with pretty undistinct and unclear yellowish rings. The worm thing can produce some spider web kind of thing which makes it stick to walls. I mean it sometimes appears to almost float against the wall/ceiling as it is hanging by its web. The spider web allows it to hang by a couple of millimetres above surface. Multiplies superbly fast like there are 20 new individuals within a day in some of the walls.
My best guess: a pupa of some moth. I spotted some moths flying around it once. Only once, in five to seven years.
enter image description here
[enter image description here[image]

India. A place close to bangladesh. Plains temperature aroung 32 deg celsius in average

[image]
[image]

Also please do tell how to get rid of these.
Insect inside has no legs. Plus the shell, it appears to have the same colour as the paint of the room. Possibly the flaky shell is made out of the particle of the wall that the insect took up.

Comment: It looks reminiscent of Luffia ferchaultella a moth larva - a  lichen eater - but not quite, too flat. I can't find references of that species in India since the 1960s either so I'm not answering but leaving it to the experts to name.

Comment: Hmmm.... the species you mentioned does resemble my insect, but my insect is thinner in depth...

Comment: I would emphasize that the insect living inside does not have legs... plus there is no lichen in my house

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What insect is this? (India)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15845/what-insect-is-this-india) See also: [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/47912/46609) and [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/28479/46609). ——— Please note that one part of the research expected of you is that you look for similar questions on this site before posting. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site for details.

Comment: @ tyersome yes i could not find these similar answers before thanks for pointing them out